# Using Watin, how can I refresh the browser when the request times out

Tags: c#, watin

I have this code:

```
var ie = new IE(); 
ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
```

I want IE auto refresh when the result is: **"Time out"**
And if IE have to load for a long time but still cannot access to http://www.google.com, Can you tell me the way to set a time out for my browser???

Answer (score 0):

you can create a background JavaScript process in the browser that sends regular heartbeats to the server. Regenerate a new cookie with timed expiration, say, every 5 or 10 minutes.

1st of all session timeout is desided and fixed by the website developer/producer.
So that we can not amend/alter the session timeout.

Session timeout is moniter by the IIS (internet information server)
Now there is only way to handle it that is regularly interacting with the server, and for this you may have two ways

1 sending hartbeets to the server by using java script

2 refresh the web page before session expires, for this you have to know about when the session going to expire.

The 2nd one is quite easy.
Consider you have a form containing webbrowser control, on its load event (form_load) event you can write as following.

```
    private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string url = "http://www.google.com"; 
      webBrowser1.Navigate(url);   
      timer1.Interval = 1000-10; // "1000" Time in millisecond that will be your maximum Session expires Time span   
      // and -10 is value that you want to refresh the page  before expire
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     webBrowser1.Refresh();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Watin? Using the .NET webbrowser you can use the onNavigate event to start a stopwatch for your timeout time and stop in the documentComplete event handler. If the stopwatch time is longer than your timeout you can do webBrowser1.Refresh(). That would be much simpler than embedding Javascript but I don't know if you can change browsers at this point.